# dompdf is not displaying images in PDF output

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, pdf, dompdf

I'm trying to use dompdf to export HTML objects as PDF document. Using text only, my example code works fine. However, when including an image in the HTML code, the image simply doesn't show up in the PDF.

I'm getting the PDF steam from an ajax request in javascript. Heres my example code:

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#export-pdf').on("click", function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "html_pdf_export.php",
            success: function (data) {

                printPDF(data, function (htmlText) {
                    var detailWindow = window.open("", "detailPDF");
                    detailWindow.document.write(htmlText);
                    console.log(htmlText);
                    detailWindow.document.close();
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
function printPDF(data, callback) {
    var pdfText = $.trim(data);
    var htmlText = '<embed width="100%" height="100%" type="application/pdf" src="data:application/pdf,'
        + encodeURI(pdfText) + '"></embed>';
    callback(htmlText);
}
```

PHP:

```
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml("<h1>Das ist ein Header</h1><p>Das ist ein Absatz unter einem Header.</p>
    <img src='./pic.jpg' style='border: 2px solid black; width: 50%;'>");

$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream();
```

Right now I am just trying to stream some hard-coded HTML code specified in the PHP file, although the end goal would be to render DOM-objects trasmitted via the ajax call.

Comment: Since you're using `loadHtml()` and a relative path for the image reference Dompdf will look for the image relative to the running PHP script. Make sure your image path is correct relative to that file. Or use an absolute path for the file system. The other option is to use a full path (with protocol and domain) but you'll need to make sure remote resource fetching is enabled. Also see the [requirements](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/Requirements) help page.

Answer (score 1):

A good option is to display your image as a base64 string, using a helper function that takes an absolute path of the image in question. An example here is in yii2 but can be implemented across all php frameworks.

```
class DompdfImageUtil{
  public static function display($path){
    $image = base64_encode(file_get_contents($path)); 

    return "data:image/png;base64,$image"; 
  }
```

Usage:

```
<?= Html::img(DompdfImageUtil::display('@app/web/image.png') ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use absolute path to image.

Comment: I've tried that, but using the absolute path ("http://localhost/html_export/pic.jpg" in my case) only shows me a black box where the image would be with the message "image not found or type unknown"

Comment: What server do you use? Can you open up the picture itself with above link?

Comment: I'm using XAMPP apache, and the link to the image works fine in my browser.

Comment: Well then try another image. Your php file is just an example right? Cause it uses nothing of the code from your javascript as I'm seeing...

Answer (score 0):

I have nearly the same problem: if I use:

`<img src="../ab/media/cd/img1.jpg">` it works, but if I use: `<img src="http://www.Mypage.com/ab/media/cd/img1.jpg">` it does not work. I want(must) be able to use dompdf with the second link, which is correct and the image is found when I paste it to the browser.

Comment: You need to set dompdf configuration option "isRemoteEnabled" to TRUE

Comment: Thanks very much this worked for me, and should be an answer for this question.