# Fetching PNG on generated PDF using DomPDF

Tags: php, html, dompdf

I'm having a problem on displaying the picture on generated PDF using DOMPDF. The version of my DomPDF is v2.0.3. And I'm using XAMPP for localhost.

This is the output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yapgg.png)

And this is the code

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Dompdf\Dompdf;

$dompdf = new Dompdf();

$html = '
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Sample PDF</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Sample PDF with Text and Image</h1>
  <p>This is a sample PDF generated using dompdf with PHP.</p>
  <img src="pic/cvsu.png" alt="CVSU Logo" style="width: 200px; height: auto;">
</body>
</html>
';

$dompdf->loadHtml($html);

$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');

$dompdf->render();

$dompdf->stream("sample_pdf.pdf", array("Attachment" => false));
?>
```

I tried solutions from other post like using ROOT, Options turning remote ON, etc., but still not working for me. I also tried to change the src link to 'http://localhost/public_html/cvsu.png' but still no use.

Comment: I've encountered this question several times before here on Stack Overflow: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37952877/adding-an-image-with-dompdf), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45708947/dompdf-is-not-displaying-images-in-pdf-output), and [so on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25558449/dompdf-image-not-readable-or-empty). Do any of the suggested solutions there work for you? I always use base64 encoding, simply because that always works.

Comment: I always use base64 encoding, simply because that always works, remember DomPDF doesn't know the location of your HTML, so relative paths don't work. Using HTTPS:// requires DomPDF to grab external content which is also not a good idea. An absolute path could work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DomPDF: Image not readable or empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25558449/dompdf-image-not-readable-or-empty)

Answer (score 0):

it worked in my case with domPDF.

```php
src="{{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}}/pic/cvsu.png"
```

Comment: what is the version of your dompdf?

Comment: v0.8.7 - it was an old project, opened the code and copied it for you

Comment: I would recommend you to go for `phpwkhtmltopdf`, in terms of speed and the work itself is much better